# What is the Software application referring to? : snap "<some package>" has "auto-refresh" change in progress

Tags: software-center, snap

Under the Software application **Updates** tab I have four Application Updates listed:
GNOME 3.28-runtime, gnome-3-34-1804, Opera, Simplenote

If I click the Update button on any one, it begins installing that package and then a popup error message says:

```
Unable to update Simplenote:
snap "simplenote" has "auto-refresh" change in progress
```

This error has recurred over the course of two hours.

Comment: Looks like this bug report https://bugs.launchpad.net/snappy/+bug/1843589 although that was filed more than a year ago.